# How to redirect page if login is not in Local Storage?

Tags: javascript

How can I redirect if the login is not done?
I'm starting in js and I'm still having difficulty with basic things...
I'm using Blogger, I've tried a few times, but I haven't been successful.

And in addition, I wanted to create a logout button to remove from local storage

This is login code + local storage:

```js
var storeS = localStorage.getItem("users");
if (storeS == null) {
  var users = [{
    username: "test",
    password: "1234"
  }];
  localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify(users));
}

function getUserUsername(username) {
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users')).filter(users => users.username === username)
}

function cheklog() {
  var login = localStorage.getItem("login");
  if (login != null && login == "true") {
    document.querySelector(".wendyloginwrap").classList.add("hidden");
  }
}
cheklog();

function startlog() {
  var username = document.querySelector("#username").value;
  var password = document.querySelector("#password").value;

  if (getUserUsername(username.trim()).length > 0) {
    var user = getUserUsername(username.trim())[0];
    if (user.password == password.trim()) {
      document.querySelector("#login-area").classList.add("hidden");
      document.querySelector("#login-true").classList.remove("hidden");
      localStorage.setItem("login", "true");
      setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.href = "#";
      }, 2000);
    } else {
      document.querySelector("#akses").innerHTML = "username or password is invalid!";
    }
  } else {
    document.querySelector("#akses").innerHTML = "username not found";
  }
}

const show = () => {
  var password = document.querySelector("#password");
  var sandi = document.querySelector(".icon1");
  var sandidua = document.querySelector(".icon2");
  if (password.type === "password") {
    password.type = "text";
    sandidua.style.opacity = "1";
    sandi.style.opacity = "0";
  } else {
    password.type = "password";
    sandidua.style.opacity = "0";
    sandi.style.opacity = "1";
  }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't do authentication checks in client-side JavaScript. The user can easily bypass it. It must be done on the server.

Comment: If you redirect when the login fails, the user will never see the message saying that the username or password is not found.

Comment: Anyway, if you want to redirect after a timeout, you can do it just like you do with the code that does `window.location.href = '#'` in `setTimeout()`.

Comment: I know, it's just for fun.

What I want is that when the visitor is not logged in and accesses the "x" page, he is redirected to the login page

Comment: When the user successfully logs in, set another local storage variable. The other page should check if that variable is set, otherwise redirect to the login page.

Comment: And the logout button simply removes that local storage variable.

Comment: Now I see you already have that: `localStorage.setItem("login", "true");`. So what's the problem? Page x should do `if (localStorage.getItem("login") != 'true')`

Comment: Works! I forgot to add the "!" in the inequality operator... 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to redirect the user to the login page you can simply use window.location.href or window.location.assign() but the check must be done on the "x" page you want to protect, like `if (localStorage.getItem("login") !== "true") //redirect to login`. For the logout button you can redirect as well and you can clear the local storage with `localStorage.clear()` (remove everythings) or `localStorage.removeItem(item)`.

Comment: This is great, thanks. However, I get flash of content on the page I am attempting to access before the redirect. Any way to prevent that?